# Ajax form data not saved in database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to save user input into database using Ajax in Laravel-5.2.

This is my `route.php`

```
Route::get('xxxxx/{task_id?}',function($task_id){
$task = App\XXXXX::find($task_id);

return response()->json($task);
});

    Route::put('xxxxx/{task_id?}',function(Request $request,$task_id){
        $task = App\XXXXX::find($task_id);

        $task->Name = $request->Name;//
        $task->Email = $request->Email;
        $task->Telephone = $request->Telephone;

        $task->save();

        return response()->json($task);
    });
```

In my view, the save button is used as.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" value="update">Save changes</button>
       <input type="hidden" id="task_id" name="task_id" value="0">
</div>
```

my js file created using [this tutorial.](http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-ajax-tutorial).

I am getting the popup, `Save` button is not working.
What is the wrong here? I m new for Ajax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Double check your application root folder name. Change the var url = "..."; to your folder name ---> from the comments

Comment: @Sachit go to Network tab in Browser's Developer tool and check XHR type. There you can see your response from server for your ajax request. It will show the errors occurred in your laravel app

Comment: replace `$("#btn-save").click(` into `$('body').on('click','#btn-save',function(){`

Answer (score 1):

**This is route.php**

Route::match(['get','post'], 'my/save-data','MyController@SaveData');

**This is your html:**

Save changes

**This is your Controller file: MyController.php**

public function SaveData( Request $request )
    { 
        $input = $request->all();

```
    try{

        // You can now use the Subscribe model without its namespace
        // as you referenced it by its namespace in a use statement.
        $subscribe = new Subscribe();

        // If you want to use a class that is not referenced in a use
        // statement then you must reference it by its full namespace.
        $otherModel = new \App\Models\Other\Namespace\OtherModel();

        $otherModel = $input['Name'];
        $otherModel = $input['Email'];
        $otherModel = $input['Telephone'];

        // save
        $otherModel->save();           

    }
    catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e)
    {
        \Log::error( $e->getMessage(), $context );              
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        \Log::error( $e->getMessage(), $context);
    }   

    return response()->json( ['status'=>'success', 'message'=>'Completed successfully'] );
}
```

---

**This is your Js file:save.js**

function save() {
    getData =   {
                    name: "value",  // from get eliment
                    email: "value", // from get eliment
                    telephone: "value" // from get eliment
                };

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',           // POST Request
    url: 'localhost/my/save-data',   // localhost/my/save-data         // Url of the Route (in this case user/save not only save)
    data: getData,         // Serialized Data

    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        // Function needed from Laravel because of the CSRF Middleware
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

        if (token) {
            return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
        }
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // Successfuly called the Controler

        // Check if the logic was successful or not
        if (data.status == 'success') {
            console.log('alles ok');
        } else {
            console.log(data.msg);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        // Error while calling the controller (HTTP Response Code different as 200 OK
        console.log('Error:', data);
    }
});
```

}